# How to pass string value in href tag

Tags: html, string, jsp, parameters

First of all I am not a regular programmer or Java expert so kindly excuse if I ask any silly question. Based on customer requirements I have to create a script which contains two pages in the home page I have three string parameter values userid, startdate and enddate which I am passing in the results page, here I am passing these string values in SQL query (this is fine), and then once the query runs successful I am extracting the results in Excel file and the excel file name I am setting using the above three string values only dynamically because this script would then be used by many users and I cannot generate a static excel file.

My problem is once the excel file is getting generated dynamically how can I pass the same string values in href tag so that I can enable a download link for the user generated Excel file, or if there is any other workaround than href? I have tried many combinations few examples below but nothing worked.

```
<a href="ExcelFolder/"+userid+"_"+startdate+"_"+enddate+".xls">Download</a> 

<input type=button onClick="parent.location='ExcelFolder"+userid+"_"+startdate+"_"+enddate+".xls'" value='click here to download in Excel'>

<button onclick="window.location.href='/ExcelFolder/"+userid+"_"+startdate+"_"+enddate+".xls'">Download</button>
```

Comment: Start by posting the real code for those 3 lines as that obviously isn't it. Surely with all that concatenation you are either storing those 3 into strings, or they're inside `out.print`s. If you post the real thing, it will be easier to fix a syntax error.

Comment: FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\tomcat\\webapps\\mywebapp\\"+userid+"_"+startdate+"_"+enddate+".xls");

The above line of code I am using to write the excel file with dynamic name taking string values from userid, startdate, enddate and it does work fine and the excel file getting created properly.

Comment: Following is the couple of out.print syntax I am using to create a download link, I have tried many other syntaxes but nothing worked, I was able to get till mywebapp location but the excel file name is being concatenated

out.println("Download <a href=mywebapp\ "+userid +startdate +enddate );
out.println("Please click <a href=mywebapp"+userid +startdate +enddate.xls>here</a> to download the file.);

Thanks a lot for looking into it

Comment: I was able to accomplish it using following code:

out.print("Please click <a href=http://mywebapp/" + userid + "_" + startdate + "_" + enddate + ".xls>here</a> to download the results in Excel");

If it can be useful for other novice like me. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish it using following code:

```css
out.print("Please click <a href=mywebapp/"; + userid + "" + startdate + "" + enddate + ".xls>here</a> to download the results in Excel");
```

If it can be useful for other novice like me.